# How to prevent RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in a finite recoursive function? | JavaScript

Tags: recursion, settimeout, minimax

I am trying to make a **Connect 4 Bot** which uses a **minimax algorithm** to function.
Apparantly going through all the possible game states is too much for my program, so I need a way to prevent the error from happening.

I saw that you could use **setTimeout()** to make big recursive functions runnable in JavaScript but I didn't really find a way to understand it.

So I wanted to ask if anybody could maybe make an example of how to implement setTimeout() into an recoursive function to make it runnable.

(Sorry for possible english mistakes.)

Answer (score 0):

I would say a better way is to use the so called iterative deepening. I don't know Javascript at all, so forgive me for posting in pseduocode/Python.

```
start_time = current_time
for depth in range(1, inf):
    score = minimax(depth, ......)

    if current_time - start_time >= max_allowed_time:
        break
```

So you get the time when you start the loop. Then you go deeper and deeper (from depth 1 and onwards) until the current time minus the time you started looping is more than your specified maximum time value. Now it will search for as deep as it can within the given time limit.

At first glance this might seem to be slower than just searching for a given depth. But it will actually speed up your code if you implement for example move ordering and transposition tables later on. And since the time for each depth goes up exponentially, the time it takes to search first depth 1, then 2, then 3 is negligible larger than searching for just depth 3 right away.

Hope I make myself clear, Englihs is not my native language either :)